# With Axios, how can I fetch all information from Pokemon API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I am using the Pokemon API with react.js to create a simple web app.

I tried to fetch all data from pokemon API and store in my array variable by doing

```
componentWillMount() {
// Called first time the comp is loaded right before the comp is added to the page
    console.log('Component WILL MOUNT!')
    var url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/"; 
    axios.get(url)

    .then((response) => {
        // setState re-renders component
        this.setState({
            pokemon: response.data
        })

        console.log(this.state.pokemon)

    })

        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
    })
}
```

This gives me the data of 811 pokemons, for example,

```
{count: 811, previous: null, results: Array(20), next: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?offset=20"}
count
:
811
next
:
"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?offset=20"
previous
:
null
results
:
Array(20)
0
:
name
:
"bulbasaur"
url
:
"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/"
__proto__
:
Object
```

But it only gives us the name of the pokemon and url of the page that gives you the exact (more detailed) information about the pokemon.

So, the url actually has to be

```
url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/" + pokemonID
```

to get the detailed information.

But my goal is to put all these information in an array, and make a searching function that displays the pokemon and its abilities. My searching function already works but right now I can only display its name.

How can I fetch all information that includes the details of each pokemon instead of its name and url for the detailed json page?

Comment: I think you have to use the second request url and fetch Pokemon's details separatelly.

Comment: I see. To do that, do we just have to make another axios request whenever we need the detail of the pokemon?

Comment: That's correct. My suggestion is having a separate method (such as `detailPokemon(pokemonId)`) which returns a promise for each Id. With that you can use Promise.all so your app waits until all requests finish.

Comment: So you mean I should create another function like clickHandler() that request for the API of the pokemon with specific ID when a button is clicked maybe?

Comment: If that suit your needs, why not? Unless you already know in advance which Ids you want to request.

Comment: So, it is valid to call multiple axios calls in different functions?